# AS3. MouseEvent click in (for) loop function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

am need here onClick one of the movieclip `loop_Task.addChild(tee)` trace the `tee.task_id.text` which one is clicked from the list for ex. this

> output be like
>    (List Clicked : 100)
>    (List Clicked : 101)

or onClick passed the item data it's already clicked to new class screen

here is my code

```
public function resultHandlerList_items(event:SQLEvent):void
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        var result:SQLResult = selectStmt1.getResult(); 
        var numResults:int = result.data.length; 
        for (var i:int = 0; i < numResults; i++) 
        {
            var row:Object = result.data[i]; 
            var tee:listview_mc = new listview_mc
            loop_Task.addChild(tee)
            tee.y = 270*i
            tee.task_id.text = row.Tid
            tee.task_tit.text = row.Ttitles
            tee.task_stime.text = row.Stime
            tee.task_subject.text = row.Subject
            tee.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickList)
        }           
        function onClickList(e:MouseEvent):void{
        trace("List Clicked : " + e.currentTarget)
        }
 }
```

Comment: This? **trace("List Clicked : " + (e.currentTarget as listview_mc).task_id.text);**

Comment: @Organis Wow That Very Good It's Work With me thanks to much

Comment: Good. The **(e.currentTarget as listview_mc)** expression here is the typecasting. The compiler does not know what **e.currentTarget** exactly is, so it's like you're saying "I'm sure this object is of **listview_mc** class, you should assume that too", so typecasting makes compiler understand what to expect from that, otherwise mysterious, object the event originates from.

Comment: yes now am understand what do you meant am still beginner in ActionScript3 , thanks so much  @Organis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in the first thanks to @Organis He give me the way to fix my code and he give me info about **how to talk with the compiler** with exactly how to make the compiler understand your code this code the fix `(e.currentTarget as listview_mc)` and now this my code after fixing and i do take a **public var String** and pass it to other **Class**

```
    public function resultHandlerList_items(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        var result:SQLResult = selectStmt1.getResult(); 
        var numResults:int = result.data.length; 
        for (var i:int = 0; i < numResults; i++) 
        {
            var row:Object = result.data[i]; 
            var tee:listview_mc = new listview_mc
            loop_Task.addChild(tee)
            tee.y = 270*i
            tee.task_id.text = row.Tid
            tee.task_tit.text = row.Ttitles
            tee.task_stime.text = row.Stime
            tee.task_subject.text = row.Subject
            tee.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickList)
        }           
        function onClickList(e:MouseEvent):void{
        trace("List Clicked : " + (e.currentTarget as listview_mc).task_id.text)
         ts_id = (e.currentTarget as listview_mc).task_id.text;
         sport._sport.Remove_Home_Sc(e);
        trace("done")        
        }
    }
```